# Converting Python notebook base64 image rendering to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I have the below Python code which renders an image from a SageMaker API endpoint in a Jupyter Notebook. This works fine.

[image: python code]

I am converting this to a web app, and I'm struggling to decode the image correctly in javascript.

My web app gets the image data response from Ruby like this:

```
    response_json = JSON.parse(response.body.string)
    response_json["images"].first
```

And this shows up in javascript like so:

[image: javascript console debug]

I try to render the image like this:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${apiResponse['data']}`} />
```

Which produces a broken image in the browser:

[image: broken image preview]

I have tried these options so far:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${apiResponse['data']}`} />
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${apiResponse['data']}`} />
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${btoa(apiResponse['data'])}`} />
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is going on in that Python `base64.decodebytes` and `np.reshape`/`np.frombuffer` code? And how to implement the same thing in javascript so I can render the image output?

Thank you

Comment: Your generated url in screenshot seems fine. Are you sure you are getting proper encoded data? You can test if your encoded data is valid [here](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: Thanks @Orifjon, yea I get the same broken image over in that tool. Something to do with encoding is wrong somewhere.